# What is wrong with my update cade?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

What is wrong with my code to update sql database the table is Informatie and i need to update the field Text.

```
$info =  nl2br($_POST["info"]);
    echo $info."<br>";
    $infoid = $_POST["infoid"];
    echo $infoid;
    echo "<br>Info ID : $infoid";
    $sql = "UPDATE Informatie set Text = $text WHERE InfoId = $infoid";
    $query = mysql_query("$sql");
```

the echo $info and $infoid are correct.

i tryd

```
$sql = "UPDATE Informatie set Text = $text WHERE InfoId = '$infoid'";
```

also but it didnt work to

Comment: What debugging have you tried? What is the simplest use case scenario? What error do you get?

Comment: Where are you setting `$text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**string values must be quoted**.

```
$sql = "UPDATE Informatie SET Text = '$text' WHERE InfoId = $infoid";
```

if `InfoID` is also a string, then you also need to wrap it with single quotes.

```
$sql = "UPDATE Informatie SET Text = '$text' WHERE InfoId = '$infoid'";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: My fault it did work but i posted the $infoid wrong ! thx !

Comment: @user2091723 did it generates error?

Comment: @user2091723 add quotes to the last '$InfoId' too.

Comment: @Meherzad if `InfoId` is int then no need to add single quote. But let's ask the OP for the datatype of `InfoId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE Informatie set Text = '$text' WHERE InfoId = '$infoid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the quoting of strings, you seem to mix up the variable names; I am guessing that `$text` should be `$info`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Informatie set Text = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($info) . "'
          WHERE InfoId = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($infoid) . "'";
```

Note that you need to escape your string to avoid your query from breaking if the text contains for example a `'` character.

But you really should switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements with bound variables.